# Mongoose hacer una consulta y lo ordene segun la cantidad de likes en un Post

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

**Consulta a la DB de los 100 post  y me lo ordene segun la cantidad de likes que tenga(Hacer un rank top 100 ordenado segun su cantidad de likes), pero me trae los post ordenado segun la creacion de like, les agradeceria si me pudieran ayudar **

```
      const today = moment().startOf("day");
  const rankTopDay = await PostArt.find({
    createdAt: {
      $gte: today.toDate(),
      $lte: moment(today).endOf("day").toDate(),
    },
  })
    .sort({ likes: -1 })
    .skip(0)
    .limit(100);

  return rankTopDay;
```

> Modelo

```
    const postArtSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  description: String,
  nickname: String,
  createdAt: Date,
  tags: [{ tag: String }],
  imageURL: { type: String },
  public_id: { type: String },
  bookmarks: [
    {
      nickname: String,
      createdAt: Date,
    },
  ],
  crown: [
    {
      typeCrown: Number,
      createdAt: Date,
    },
  ],
  comments: [
    {
      body: String,
      nickname: String,
      createdAt: Date,
    },
  ],
  likes: [
    {
      nickname: String,
      createdAt: Date,
      typeLike: Number,
    },
  ],
  views: [
    {
      nickname: String,
      createdAt: Date,
    },
  ],
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "users",
  },
});
```

*Lo intente hacer con agregate pero solo me devuelve el contenido de los likes q todos los post y no los post en si*

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta es que estas ordenando según un campo que es un array de documento, internamente Mongo no interpreta que debe realizar el ordenado por el tamaño del array, por lo que seguramente te devuelve los datos según los iba creando en la colección.

Te muestro una solución a tu problema:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
       createdAt: {
         $gte: today.toDate(),
         $lte: moment(today).endOf("day").toDate()
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: { // A cada documento, creamos un nuevo documento vacío
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [ // Unimos el documento raíz y añadimos un campo "countLikes" el cual ponemos la longitud del array Likes
          {
            countLikes: {
              $size: "$$ROOT.likes" // Tamaño de campo "likes"
            }
          },
          "$$ROOT" // Documento raíz
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      countLikes: -1 // Ordenamos 
    }
  },
  {
    $skip: 0
  },
  {
    $limit: 100
  }
])
```

Te recomiendo que uses el método `aggregate` para realizar búsquedas ya que tiene muchas etapas y métodos que te ayudaran a realizar consultas complicadas.

Espero que con esto pueda ayudarte a resolver tu problema, para cualquier cosa no dudes en preguntar.

Un saludo